# Box2d - Bike Game - Terrain

Tags: physics, box2d, terrain

I'm using **Box2d** for a Bike Physics Game, Box2d lets you have fixtures that are **convex polygons with 8 points or less**, would anyone know of an easier way have a **complicated concave terrain**, other than just making a whole bunch of fixtures? Or is that the only way?

Any ideas, pointers, suggestions... Thanks in advance! (any language is OK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look to this URL: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/06/two-ways-to-make-box2d-cars/ specially the second example.

Hope it helps!